# Predictive Modeling Birth Count Data (with Linear Regression)

Tags: r

I was given this data (below) and I want to try some predictive modeling with the data. Specifically, I want to build a linear regression to predict birth counts (by month, if possible) until the year 2032. I assume I will have to use the `predict()` function.

Here are my data

In wide format:

```
> dput(births_monthly_cross_022822_clean)
structure(list(month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
), `2010` = c(323816, 302551, 339219, 325582, 328960, 335180, 
345875, 350473, 351439, 337477, 326868, 339665), `2011` = c(321104, 
298537, 330752, 313875, 327242, 337890, 346192, 360079, 346254, 
329174, 322135, 327986), `2012` = c(316959, 305060, 324944, 307262, 
330779, 327811, 348157, 361902, 340901, 346251, 325810, 324960
), `2013` = c(324314, 292360, 321166, 312274, 330193, 320475, 
349920, 354293, 338863, 341353, 319233, 336320), `2014` = c(327154, 
299087, 324317, 319788, 335444, 326757, 356446, 355201, 349403, 
344265, 318819, 341494), `2015` = c(326747, 298815, 329714, 321618, 
328709, 331400, 354384, 352782, 348479, 339904, 319605, 336576
), `2016` = c(317445, 306750, 329341, 314312, 328434, 333166, 
343643, 358737, 346525, 331939, 320258, 325562), `2017` = c(314597, 
289694, 320327, 300801, 323169, 324633, 335708, 353033, 338012, 
330762, 317280, 316738), `2018` = c(315593, 284940, 316824, 299125, 
321448, 315585, 329851, 345687, 323685, 327740, 309475, 311581
), `2019` = c(311678, 280679, 304999, 299755, 317160, 304843, 
334518, 342617, 326662, 326165, 298899, 309607), `2020` = c(305536, 
283385, 302331, 290940, 301902, 302574, 322096, 320072, 312152, 
305548, 283010, 290280)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(month = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `2010` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2011` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2012` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2013` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2014` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2015` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2016` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2017` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2018` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2019` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector")), `2020` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_number", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Same data but in long format:

```
> dput(Birthcount)
structure(list(month = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
12, 12, 12, 12), name = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
"2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", 
"2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", 
"2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", 
"2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", 
"2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", 
"2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
"2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", 
"2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", 
"2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020"), value = c(323816, 
321104, 316959, 324314, 327154, 326747, 317445, 314597, 315593, 
311678, 305536, 302551, 298537, 305060, 292360, 299087, 298815, 
306750, 289694, 284940, 280679, 283385, 339219, 330752, 324944, 
321166, 324317, 329714, 329341, 320327, 316824, 304999, 302331, 
325582, 313875, 307262, 312274, 319788, 321618, 314312, 300801, 
299125, 299755, 290940, 328960, 327242, 330779, 330193, 335444, 
328709, 328434, 323169, 321448, 317160, 301902, 335180, 337890, 
327811, 320475, 326757, 331400, 333166, 324633, 315585, 304843, 
302574, 345875, 346192, 348157, 349920, 356446, 354384, 343643, 
335708, 329851, 334518, 322096, 350473, 360079, 361902, 354293, 
355201, 352782, 358737, 353033, 345687, 342617, 320072, 351439, 
346254, 340901, 338863, 349403, 348479, 346525, 338012, 323685, 
326662, 312152, 337477, 329174, 346251, 341353, 344265, 339904, 
331939, 330762, 327740, 326165, 305548, 326868, 322135, 325810, 
319233, 318819, 319605, 320258, 317280, 309475, 298899, 283010, 
339665, 327986, 324960, 336320, 341494, 336576, 325562, 316738, 
311581, 309607, 290280)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -132L))
```

So far, my crude model is as follows:

```
mod.fert.natl <- lm( value ~ name, data = Birthcount)
```

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: So what exactly is your question? If you want advice about creating a prediction model, then you should really ask for help at [stats.se] where statistical questions are on topic. This doesn't seem to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: And use the `time-series` and `forecasting` tags on Cross Validated.

Comment: And also be aware that on Cross Validated the standard for how to ask good questions is different than on OS. https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Taking your data in long format, we need to change a few things. The years should be numeric if we want to model long term trends. The months will be easier to track if we make them factors with the correct ordering. We should also create a date column that allows us to combine the year and month for plotting, and we should give all these columns representative names:

```r
Birthcount <- dplyr::transmute(Birthcount, 
                               date  = as.Date(paste(name, month, 1, sep = '-')),
                               month = factor(month.name[month], month.name), 
                               year  = as.numeric(name),
                               count = value)
```

Now creating a model is straightforward. When you are dealing with count data, you should ideally use a `glm` with `family = poisson`, but when you are dealing with count data in the hundreds of thousands and where the minimum value is also in the hundreds of thousands, it really doesn't make any practical difference whether you use a `glm` or `lm` (see the addendum). To be rigorous here, let's use a `glm`.

Assuming you want to model a seasonal variation of births over months, and a trend over years, you could do:

```r
mod <- glm(count ~ month + year, data = Birthcount, family = poisson)
```

To get the predictions out to 2032, we need a new data frame of the years and months we wish to predict.

```
new_df <- expand.grid(month = factor(month.name, month.name), year = 2010:2032)
new_df$date <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2032-12-01"), by = "month")
```

Now we can add our predicted counts:

```r
new_df$count <- predict(mod, newdata = new_df)
```

Now `new_df` contains all our predictions. To see what this looks like, we can plot the predictions and the actual data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Birthcount, aes(date, count)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = "Predicted"), data = new_df, linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = "Actual")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("red4", "gray80")) +
  ggtitle("Monthly births (Actual and Predicted) 2010 - 2032") +
  labs(colour = "") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**

If we examine the predictions between a `glm` and an `lm`, we will see that there is little practical difference for prediction purposes.

```
mod_glm <- mod
mod_lm  <- lm(count ~ month + year, data = Birthcount)

plot(predict(mod_glm, type = "response"), predict(mod_lm))
abline(a = 0, b = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to fit a linear model to count data?

Comment: @dipetkov in general no, you would use a glm with Poisson family and a log link function, but in cases when you are dealing with counts in the hundreds of thousands this distinction doesn't make any practical difference. I'll try this out with a glm to see once I'm back at my PC, but my guess is there will be little if any difference.

Comment: The OP and many people who stumble upon this Q&A might not know this. I think your answer would benefit from having a banner along the lines of "There are more appropriate models for counts data". And better ways to model time series for that matter.

Comment: @dipetkov I get the impression the OP is a beginner, and didn't think this was a great time to make a distinction where it doesn't make a difference - it's a difficult call to make, since you don't want to make something more complex than it needs to be, but don't want to be inaccurate either. I suspect you wouldn't have any problem using linear models when dealing with, say, dollar values between $3000 and $4000, even though these are technically whole numbers of cents in 300,000 to 400,000 range.

Comment: @dipetkov but you're not wrong, and I will add a footnote when I get back to my PC.

Comment: I agree with you! For a bit I thought about showing how to fit a time series model to this data but then I thought -- no, this is too involved. But I still think it's better to point about that to get it right, the analysis will have to be more involved. And then point the OP to Cross Validated. Then it's up to them to decide how much in the weeds they want to get.

Comment: Interesting discussion, thank you all. I am actually familiar with Poisson models and considered the model. Would the correct model specification be `summary(m1 <- glm(count ~ month + year, family="poisson", data=Birthcount))` ? Also, thank you all for your help.

Comment: yes, that would be more 'technically' correct, but I don't think the predictions would be any different. You might also want to look into modelling this as a time series as @dipetkov suggests